# CONNECT BY for two tables with two JOINS

Tags: oracle, hierarchical, aggregate

I have 3 tables:

- two with hierarchical structures
  (like "dimensions" of recursive type of hierarchy);
- one with summing data (like "facts" with X column).

They are here:

1. DIM1 (ID1, PARENT2, NAME1)
2. DIM2 (ID2, PARENT2, NAME2)
3. FACTS (ID1, ID2, X)

Example of DIM1 table:

```
--        1   0  DIM1  
----      2   1  DIM1-A  
------    3   2  DIM1-A-A  
--------  4   3  DIM1-A-A-A  
--------  5   3  DIM1-A-A-B  
------    6   2  DIM1-A-B  
--------  7   6  DIM1-A-B-A  
--------  8   6  DIM1-A-B-B  
------    9   2  DIM1-A-C  
----     10   1  DIM1-B  
------   11  10  DIM1-B-C  
------   12  10  DIM1-B-D  
----     13   1  DIM1-C
```

Example of DIM2 table:

```
--        1   0  DIM2  
----      2   1  DIM2-A  
------    3   2  DIM2-A-A  
--------  4   3  DIM2-A-A-A  
--------  5   3  DIM2-A-A-B  
--------  6   3  DIM2-A-B-C  
------    7   2  DIM2-A-B  
----      8   1  DIM2-B  
----      9   1  DIM2-C
```

Example of FACTS table:

```
 1   1  100  
 1   2   30  
 1   3  500  
 --    ................  
 13  9  200
```

And I would like to create **the only** `SELECT` where I will specify the parent for DIM1 (for example `ID1=2` for DIM1-A) and parent for DIM2 (for example `ID2=2` for DIM2-A) and `SELECT` will generate a report like this:

```
Name_of_1 Name_of_2 Sum_of_X  
--------- --------- ----------  
DIM1-A-A  DIM2-A-A  (some sum)  
DIM1-A-A  DIM2-A-B  (some sum)  
DIM1-A-B  DIM2-A-A  (some sum)  
DIM1-A-B  DIM2-A-B  (some sum)  
DIM1-A-C  DIM2-A-A  (some sum)  
DIM1-A-C  DIM2-A-B  (some sum)
```

I would like to use `CONNECT BY` phrase, `START WITH` phrase, `SUM` phrase, `GROUP BY` phrase, and `OUTER` or `INNER` (?) `JOIN`.  I need no other extensions of Oracle 10.2.

In other words: only with "classic" SQL and
only Oracle extensions for hierarchy queries.

Is it possible?

I tried some experiments with question in
[Mixing together Connect by, inner join and sum with Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922167/mixing-together-connect-by-inner-join-and-sum-with-oracle)

(where is a very **nice solution** but only for **one**
dimension table ("Tasks"), but I need to `JOIN` **two** dimension tables to one facts table), but I was not successful.

Answer (score 2):

"Some sum" is not very descriptive, so I don't see why do you need `CONNECT BY` at all.

```
SELECT  dim1.name, dim2.name, x
FROM    (
        SELECT  id1, id2, SUM(x) AS x
        FROM    facts
        GROUP BY
                id1, id2
        ) f
JOIN    dim1
ON      dim1.id = f.id1
JOIN    dim2
ON      dim2.id = f.id2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is get the sum of the value in the facts table for all of the children of the specified rows grouped by the topmost children.  This would mean that in your example above, the results for the first row would be the sum any intersections of (DIM1-A-A, DIM1-A-A-A, DIM1-A-A-B) and (DIM2-A-A, DIM2-A-A-A, DIM2-A-A-B, DIM3-A-A-C) found in the FACTS table.  With that assumption, I have come to the following solution:

```
SELECT root_name1, root_name2, SUM(X)
FROM ( SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT(name1) AS root_name,
             id1
         FROM dim1
      CONNECT BY parent1 = PRIOR id1
      START WITH parent1 = 2) d1
     CROSS JOIN
     ( SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT(name2) AS root_name,
              id2
         FROM dim2
      CONNECT BY parent2 = PRIOR id2
      START WITH parent2 = 2) d2
     LEFT OUTER JOIN
     facts
     ON     d1.id1 = facts.id1
        AND d2.id2 = facts.id2
GROUP BY root_name1, root_name2
```

(This also assumes that the columns of FACTS are named ID1, ID2, and X.)